# Nginx giving 404 error for WordPress' /wp-admin/ root

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm using the following nginx block to route mysite.com/blog to my /var/www/mysite/wordpress/ directory:

```
location /blog {
    root /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
    rewrite ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/ gives me a 404 error. Visiting mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php works as expected, so it looks like my index rule is not working. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to solve this issue using `alias` directive:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    alias /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```